# function call not accepting my arguments

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error when I try to call a function that I have overloaded to accept cuComplex which is a structure from CUDA.

```
../common/Filter.cpp:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘ReaderIF::getData(float2&, int&)’
../readers/ReaderIF.h:63: note: candidates are: virtual bool ReaderIF::getData(cuComplex*, offset)
../readers/ReaderIF.h:65: note: virtual bool ReaderIF::getData(std::complex<float>*, offset)
../readers/ReaderIF.h:82: note: virtual bool ReaderIF::getData(float*, offset)
```

why am I getting this?

here is how i called the getData function:

```
cuComplex *h_hhBuff = (cuComplex *)malloc(memsize);
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)

{
hhReader->getData(h_hhBuff[r*cols], r);
}
```

since I am clearly casting the malloc as a cuComplex, shouldnt I be able to call that first candidate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have indexed your pointer, which has dereferenced it, so it is no longer a `cuComplex *`, but a `cuComplex`.  Perhaps you want to do the following:

```
hhReader->getData(&h_hhBuff[r*cols], r);
```